# What make/model of bike do I have?

Tags: identify-this-bike

tThis was given to me from a family member that is no longer with us. I cannot for the life of me figure out the make/model.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Looks a lot like [this](https://himiwaybike.com/products/all-terrain-electric-fat-bike-31?variant=31874658336843&currency=USD&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&gclid=Cj0KCQjwnqH7BRDdARIsACTSAdu2fIJFKlFs_qNa_uSGJm4vQ09E0qd-b_w4XO6Lsuc6J8MymiF0ZMYaAmWGEALw_wcB) one, though the frame may be generic.

Comment: Its an electric fat bike - not something that the common manufacturers get into.  Is there some specific reason you need a brand name?   The standards to which the parts are built are relatively generic.

Comment: Crigie-thanks for commenting....I am looking to sell it online and wanted to be able to call out the make/model in the post.